# Reference Jar within main Jar to pass as javaagent to JVM

Tags: java, jar, javaagents, alpn, pushy

I need to add a `-javaagent` argument in my JVM args when running jar1, but reference jar2 that is contained within jar1.  I have tried:

```
-javaagent:BOOT-INF/lib/jetty-alpn-agent-2.0.0.jar"
```

with no success.  How do I determine the location of JARs within a running system at runtime?

(This is to run `jetty-alpn-agent-2.0.0.jar` as a Java Agent for HTTP/2 use with Pushy APNs)

Comment: Did you ever find solution to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@indusBull

The solution that worked for me was to define a property called `libDirectory` in my `gradle.properties` file, which was the location of where the JARs are located in a running system, and then reference that variable from my `Dockerfile`:

**gradle.properties**

```
libDirectory = /opt/meanwhileinhell/app/lib
```

**Dockerfile**

```
ENTRYPOINT  ["java",\
            ...
            ...
            "-javaagent:${libDirectory}/jetty-alpn-agent.jar",\
            "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the class is on the class path, you can typically do:

```
URL jar = MainClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

The Javaagent is always loaded on the class path which is why you should be able to reference the main class of the regular application.